# Text Trimming in the Button

Tags: xaml, button, windows-phone-8, texttrimming

I'm trying to trim text in a button, when it is to long, but it doesn't work. This is my Button:

```
    <Button x:Name="button" Margin="-6,0,-6,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" Click="button_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource ButtonInputButtonStyle}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
        <Image x:Name="buttonImage" Visibility="Collapsed" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="buttonTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Label, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Please be sure to tag the technology/language you are using.

Comment: Give width or maxwidth to textblock.